# Determing encoding of "file.ini"

Tags: python, encoding

I work with configuration file "myfile.ini" and use "codecs.open" function from "codecs" module

```
import codecs
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

f = codecs.open('myfile.ini', mode='r', encoding=???)
```

In advance i don't know "myfile.ini" encoding (it could be changed by user when he saved file)

I known that there is no correct way to determine file encoding and try following:

```
arr = ['utf8', 'ascii', ...other_encodings...]
err=0
for enc in arr:
    try:
        conf = SafeConfigParser()
                with codecs.open('myfile.ini', 'r', encoding=enc) as f:
                    conf.readfp(f)

                config = conf.get('a', 'b')
                f.close()
                encoding = enc
     except Exeption as EX:
        err+=1
        continue

print 'file encoding: ', encoding
```

But, unfortunately it doesn't work properly.

Is there any way to determine "myfile.ini" encoding or may be set permanent encoding for this file adding some script to it?

Comment: Have a look at [ConfigParser](http://pymotw.com/2/ConfigParser/) and [ConfigParserDocs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Comment: i use ConfigParser to parse "myfile.ini" after opening and get data, but in advance i must open file in correct encoding, or this module also provides techniques for determing/setting file encoding?

Comment: This module should be able to recognize the encoding and that's why is able to read data from the INI file. Providing correct encoding means - you must know what is the encoding in advance / custom encoding. In [this link](http://pymotw.com/2/ConfigParser/), search for the line **Open the file with the correct encoding**, you will find a code section that uses both `codecs` and `ConfigParser` to solve it.

Comment: "But, unfortunately it doesn't work properly." - how is it not working properly? Where is the problem in your code?

Comment: mhawke, i use the very same technique as Tanmaya Meher suggested (i edited code above a little). 
but when i saved file in "utf-8" and open it using script above, i get "MissingSectionHeaderError File contains no section headers."
But i know that my file contains this section. Therefore i think that "codecs.open" used not correct encoding

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [chardet](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) package.

```
>>> import chardet
>>> chardet.detect(open('/etc/passwd').read())
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
```

Another option is to use libmagic (the basis of the unix `file` command). There is a Python binding available as [python-magic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic).

```
>>> import magic
>>> m = magic.Magic(mime_encoding=True)
>>> m.from_file('/etc/passwd')
'us-ascii'
```